# When using a before_filter on creation of a new record, how do I skip to next record if a duplicate is found?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a `Question` and `Tag` model.

I am doing this in my `Question` model:

```
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags, before_add: :validates_tag

  def validates_tag(tag)
    if self.tags.include? tag
      next
    end
  end
```

But I am getting a:

```
SyntaxError: /app/models/question.rb:30: Invalid next
    from /app/models/question.rb
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the conditional and return `self.tags.include? tag` from `#validates_tag`? Does the entire action/operation fail?

Comment: that works! If you add that as an answer, I will accept that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `#validates_tag` to:

```
def validates_tag(tag)
  self.tags.include? tag
end
```